# Declare a variable of changing type inside a if-statement and using it outside of statement

Tags: c++, scope, arguments, variable-assignment

I have a program that's reading in the command line argument to choose between one of three algorithms. Because each different argument would need a different variable type, I can't create a null variable before the if-statement. How can I set this up so that the program compiles?

```
std::string argType = argv[1];
if (argType =="Type_A") {
    outPrint="Ty_A";
    AlgoPick<Type_A> algorithm = AlgoPick<Type_A>();
} else if (argType =="Type_B") {
    outPrint="Ty_B";
    AlgoPick<Type_B> algorithm = AlgoPick<Type_B>();
} else {
    outPrint="Ty_O";
    AlgoPick<Type_O> algorithm = AlgoPick<Type_O>();
}

std::cout << algorithm.eval() << std::endl;
```

Trying to pre-declare the variable and overwrite it led to weird behavior.

```
AlgoPick<Type_A> algorithm

AlgoPick<Type_B> algorithm = AlgoPick<Type_B>();
/*Trying to do this led to a mesh of both Type_A and Type_B logic instead of just Type_B.*/
```

Comment: place the `std::cout ...` inside each of the branches?

Comment: This would be easier if you were using polymorphism instead of templates...

Comment: Does the signature of `eval()` change depending on the template argument? If not, then make `AlgoPick<T>` derive from a non-template base class, move `eval()` to that class, and make it `virtual`. Then use polymorphism to call `eval()` at runtime.  If that is not an option, then use `std::variant` for the variable and `std::visit()` to call `eval()` on whatever is stored in the `variant`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai There's about 20 line that would need to be in each branch, but I think that's honestly the easiest thing to do simplicity-wise.

Comment: @AliCamilletti *"There's about 20 line that would need to be in each branch,"* -- Not if those 20 lines were collected into a function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the signature of `eval()` does not change depending on the template argument, then make `AlgoPick<T>` derive from a non-template base class, move `eval()` to that class, and make it `virtual`. Then use polymorphism to call `eval()` at runtime.

```
class AlgoPickBase {
public:
    virtual ~AlgoPickBase() = default;
    virtual returnType eval() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class AlgoPick : public AlgoPickBase {
public:
    returnType eval() override {
        ...
    }
};

...

std::string argType = argv[1];
std::unique_ptr<AlgoPickBase> algorithm;
if (argType == "Type_A") {
    outPrint = "Ty_A";
    algorithm = std::make_unique<AlgoPick<Type_A>>();
} else if (argType =="Type_B") {
    outPrint = "Ty_B";
    algorithm = std::make_unique<AlgoPick<Type_B>>();
} else {
    outPrint = "Ty_O";
    algorithm = std::make_uniqu<AlgoPick<Type_O>>();
}

std::cout << algorithm->eval() << std::endl;
```

If that is not an option, then use `std::variant` for the variable, and `std::visit()` to call `eval()` on whatever object is stored in the `variant`.

```
std::string argType = argv[1];
std::variant<AlgoPick<Type_B>, AlgoPick<Type_B>, AlgoPick<Type_O>> algorithm;

if (argType == "Type_A") {
    outPrint = "Ty_A";
    algorithm = AlgoPick<Type_A>();
} else if (argType == "Type_B") {
    outPrint = "Ty_B";
    algorithm = AlgoPick<Type_B>();
} else {
    outPrint = "Ty_O";
    algorithm = AlgoPick<Type_O>();
}

std::visit(
    [](auto&& alg){
        std::cout << alg.eval() << std::endl;
    }, algorithm
);
```